# Properly pass class type on generic function to create new class of any type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to understand and learn more on generics in typescript and wanted to know why this does not work. I have spent a lot of hours reading about generics and types but for the life of me I cannot understand what I have done wrong.

Example:

```
abstract class Employee {
  constructor(
    public identifier: string
  ) {}
}

class FinanceEmployee extends Employee {
  empType: string;
  constructor(
    identifier: string
  ) {
    super(identifier);
    this.empType = "Finance";
  }
}

class MarketingEmployee extends Employee {
  empType: string;
  constructor(
    identifier: string
  ) {
    super(identifier);
    this.empType = "Marketing";
  }
}

type EmployeeType<T> = new (identifier: string) => T;

let count = 0;

function createEmployee<T>(ctor: EmployeeType<T>):void {
  const employee = new ctor(`employee-${count++}`);
  console.log(employee.identifier);
  console.log(employee.empType);
}

createEmployee(FinanceEmployee);
createEmployee(MarketingEmployee);
```

Typescript errors and tells me that identifier and empType do not exist on type T...

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `createEmployee` type, there isn't any information about what `ctor` actually returns, only that it's some type `T`.

You can add a constraint to `T` so that inside the function, we have more information about what `T` will actually be, and to also restrict what type of constructor can be passed in:

```
function createEmployee<T extends Employee & { empType: string }>(ctor: EmployeeType<T>): void {
  const employee = new ctor(`employee-${count++}`);
  console.log(employee.identifier);
  console.log(employee.empType);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your response. My question to this, is that I am using generics because we dont know exactly what will be passed in (except for in this case we know it has to have identifier and empType of course). Lets say the function was printing out all the keys and values in of the items passed in, but we dont know the exact properties for example.

Comment: @tljw86 You could constrain it to be `Record<string, any>` That will let you access any property, but If you do have a set of specific properties I would define those as the constraint as it will be more type safe.